# How can i integrate RASA kit working with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rasa-nlu

I have made A chatbot as a webpage function. the database i have used in the background is the mongodb. but due to intelligence i want to add RASA instead of mongodb.

I have understood the desgining of the rasa files but what i didn't understand is the integration of rasa with the nodejs.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Chatbot_Project";
var bodyParse = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParse.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db = client.db("Chatbot_Project");
    var data = db.collection('Questions').find();
    data.forEach(function(results, err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var string = JSON.stringify(results);
        global.str = string.substring(string.indexOf("Apply") + 9, string.indexOf("Where To Apply") - 3);
    });
});
```

this is what i have done to integrade mongodb with node. but what should i do to integrate 'rasa botkit' with node.

Answer (score 8):

Rasa NLU and Core can present themselves as HTTP servers. Documentation links below. Once you've trained them following their own documentation you can then call their HTTP api with a standard node library like request or wreck. Then do whatever you want with the responses.

### Basics

As an example you can start Rasa in docker:

```
docker run -p5000:5000 rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-spacy
```

Then train a model, make sure to use your training data file instead of `my_training_data.json`

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:5000/train?project=my_project \
-d @my_training_data.json
```

Once that is finished you can call the `/parse` endpoint from the node library of your choice, like request:

```
var request = require('request');

var queryString = { project:'my_project' };
var url = 'http://localhost:5000/parse'

request({url:url, qs: queryString}, function(err, response, body) {
 if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
 console.log("Get response: " + response.statusCode);
});
```

### Documentation

- [Rasa NLU](https://nlu.rasa.com/http.html)
- [Rasa Core](https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_remote.html)

### Pre-Built Alternatives

As a note there are a couple of UI's that run over the top of Rasa NLU and integrate with databases and webhooks

- [Articulate](https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate) (I am a member of their team)
- [Rasa UI](https://github.com/paschmann/rasa-ui)
- [Rasa Talk](https://github.com/jackdh/RasaTalk)

using one of these could prevent you from having to write as much code.

Answer (score 1):

There is "rasa-api" a Node.js package that will enables you to access Rasa HTTP API in a convenient way: https://github.com/Hexastack/rasa-api

You can just do `npm install rasa-api` and start using it ;)